# Can not download image using html5 download attribute

Tags: html, download

I was trying to download image on click of button. so the instead of download its opening in tab. i don't know whats going wrong because when i try any other url like then its downloading the image.

here is the code which is opening image instead of downloading.

```
<a href="https://storage.googleapis.com/iwh/1523362956000-EI201500016-95315cd9afb9476e42cf388bc97e0ecdaa40c562.jpeg" download>
```

here is the code which is downloading image.

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

you can try this here ..
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download

Answer (score -2):

You need to put  tag inside  tag for download functionality

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

Comment: that's working  i know but if you replace image path (the above one) it won't be download.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing the same. Its dowloading the image if path is given as '/path/filename' and if you are providing path as the http url its just opening it. I am expecting this behaviour as a property of the browser.

Comment: is there any way that i can call 'Save as image' from function on button click ?